Running out of RAM with Bitcoin Core
I'm encountering a persistent issue with RAM exhaustion while running Bitcoin Core on my system. Here's a brief overview of the problem:
Problem Description:
I have a Bitcoin Core node set up on my system, and I query it every minute using an python script consulting for new blocks and query every tx using API REST.
Despite setting the 'dbcache' parameter in my bitcoin.conf file to the default value of 450MB, I've noticed a gradual increase in RAM consumption over time.
To solve this problem I must close bitcoin core and reopen it from time to time
09:00:00

16:49:00

